# React onCLick required is not working ? My page is refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code like that when i click the create button my page is not refreshing but required part is not working when I try to not OnClick onSubmit this time required is work but when i click the button page is refreshing ı dont know why I write e.preventDefault() but not working anyone help ?

```
createAdmin =(e) =>{
e.preventDefault();
}


 <input type="input" className="form__field" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name"  required />
 <input type="input" className="form__field" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name"  required />
 <input type="input" className="form__field" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name"  required />
<button  onClick={this.createAdmin}>Create</button>
```

Comment: More info required

Comment: can you edit the code to show the full component as i have an idea but cant be sure without seeing the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

The preventDefault() method is used to prevent the default action for a button. So basically, createAdmin function is not doing anything at all.

Clicking on a button will not refresh your page for sure. I can't say anymore unless I look at the other parts of your code

Answer (score 1):

Im going to suggest that this is simply a case of functional vs class components and a mix up with the use of 'this'

If this is a functional component: -

Add const to the function as below

```
const createAdmin = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
}
```

Change the button call to

```
<button onClick = {createAdmin}> Create Admin </button>
```

If this is a class component, not a functional component the syntax would be

```
createAdmin(e) {
e.preventDeafult()
}
```

In the second case the button syntax is correct as you have it now